# Rails 3 head first rails Mebay application error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

A `NoMethodError` is showing when I try to run my Rails 3 application:

> NoMethodError in Ads#show
>
> Showing C:/Ruby193/RailsProject/MeBay/app/views/ads/show.html.erb
>   where line #7 raised:
>
> undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass Extracted source (around line #7):
>
> ```
> 4: </head>
> 5: <body>
> 6: <p>
> 7:   <b>Name:</b>><%= @ad.name %>
> 8: </p>
> 9: <p>
> 10:  <b>Description:</b><%= @ad.description %>
> ```

I am replicating the `Mebay` application with ads table in chapter 2 of the 'Head First Rails' book

On the command line, this is what I did:

```
$ rails new MeBay 
$ cd to MeBay directory
$ rails g model ad name:string description:text price:decimal seller_id:integer email:string imr_url:string
$ rake db:migrate
$ rails generate controller ads
```

At this point, the `show.html.erb` file was created in the folder `app/views/ads`, and its code is as follows:

```
 <html>
    <head>
      <title> </title> 
    </head>
    <body>
    <p>
      <b>Name:</b>
    </p>
    <p>
     <b>Description:</b>
    </p>
    <p>
     <b>Price:</b>
    </p>
    <p>
     <b>Seller Id:</b>
    </p>
    <p>
     <b>Email:</b>
    </p>

    </body>
    </html>
```

This is my `config/routes.rb` file:

```
MeBay::Application.routes.draw do
    controller 'ads' do
           match 'ads/:id' => :show
   end

end
```

When I started the Rails server and loaded the page in the browser (`http://locathost:3000/ads/3`) I only see labels with empty values. I don't see values next to the labels as the book indicates should happen on page 63.

Page 65 indicates that the application should tell the model to read the record from the ads table in the database. But I have created only the ads table I don't have values entered in database for this application, like the page 65 example shows.

When I don't have data, I added the code, like page 69 says, in `views/ads/show.html.erb` as:

```
 <html>
    <head>
      <title> </title> 
    </head>
    <body>
    <p>
      <b>Name:</b><%= @ad.name %>
    </p>
    <p>
     <b>Description:</b><%= @ad.description %>
    </p>
    <p>
     <b>Price:</b><%= @ad.price %>
    </p>
    <p>
     <b>Seller Id:</b><%= @ad.seller_id %>
    </p>
    <p>
     <b>Email:</b><%= @ad.email %>
    </p>
    <p>
     <img src="<%= @ad.img_url %>"/>
    </p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I am stuck at this point, with the above error. Please help on this error or where /how would I enter data in table. I have searched all forums and worked on this error for hours. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Had you paid attention while reading the book, you would have noticed that on Page 51, they tell you to download the seed data required for the app from here : http://www.headfirstlabs.com/books/hfrails/.

Do this, and try again, it will work.